# responsetext displays php code from server without executing

Tags: php, xmlhttprequest, responsetext

Developing an app on phonegap installed on local machine. Everything works on localhost as well as when i run it as website on webhost for testing purpose(1freehosting). 
However when i try to just access a php script so that it can query a mysql db and return the results as responsetext(in html+php results format) the results are not good.
 Here is my code:

```
function getData(oFormElement){
//alert(oFormElement);
    if (oFormElement == "") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
    return;
} else {
    //alert(4);

    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp.onload = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
    alert(xmlhttp.readyState);    
 alert(xmlhttp.status);
    if (xmlhttp.readyState < 4) {
        //alert(6);   
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "loading..............";
        }
        else if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert(5);   
        alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
         }
    }

        xmlhttp.open("post","http://www.website.com/get_data.php",false);

        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","multipart/form-data");

        xmlhttp.send(new FormData(oFormElement));

    return false;

}
}
</script>

<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <br>
Category:<br>
<select name="Category" id="Category" onchange="change(this.id);">
  <option value="item1">item1</option>
  <option value="item2">item2</option>

  </select>
<br>
    Sub Category:<br>
<select name="SubC" id="SubC" >
  <option value="">Please select a Sub Category</option>
</select>
<br>
Chose your Area:<br>
<select name="Area" id="Area">
  <option value="">Please select an Area</option>
</select>
<br>
<input class="button" id="button" value="Discountz" type="button"  onclick="return getData(this);" > 
</form>

<div id="txtHint">
</div>
```

My php code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
</style>
</head>
<body>

<?php

require_once __DIR__ . '/dbconfig_d.php';
//echo $_POST["Category"];
$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVR,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error());

if(isset($_POST["item1"]) && isset($_POST["item2"]) &&  isset($_POST["item3"])){

$item1 = $_POST["item1"];
$item2 = $_POST["item2"];
$item3 = $_POST["item3"];

$result = mysqli_query($db,"select * from table_1 where item1 = '$item1' and item2 = '$item2' and Area = '$item3'")
      or die(mysqli_error($db));

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

       echo "<table>";

         echo "<tr> ";
         echo "<col style='width:30%;'><col style='width:70%;'>";
         echo "<td>" . $row["item1"] . " in " ."<br>". $row["item2"] . "</td>";
         echo "<td>" . $row["item4"].  "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
        echo "</a>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    mysqli_close($db);
}}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

First i was getting just html code in responsetext. later i created .htaccess and put 'AddType application/x-httpd-php5 .htm .html .php'. After this i am getting only php code in response text but no executed result.

I checked many posts and based on those added headers/htaccess which helped in atleast getting responsetext.

Kindly help.

you can ignore field names etc also since i modified them for putting here.

Comment: Best bet is to get on to 1freehosting's support and make sure their service allows PHP.

Comment: Side note: You're using `mysqli_*` without using [one of its most important feature](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Also, it's kind of pointless to use `ActiveXObject` fallback on a cordova (phonegap) app.

Comment: i had added CORS statements in php code also but it did not make any difference.

Comment: @Kevin, they allow php since my website hosted there works but when i invoke only the php part(to fetch data from mysql db on host) it returns either html or php(after adding .htaccess) without executing the code.                                                 Passerby . The mysql works in 2 scenarios(either implementing whole solution on localhost or implementing it as website on webhost) but not working when implementing from localhost to webhost.